# What is the API used to add/remove/manage users of AWS Directory Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, samba, aws-directory-services

I am trying to programmatically add users to a "Simple AD" in the AWS Directory Service. There is indeed an API for managing the directory itself (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/devguide/API_Operations.html), but I am unable to find anything similar for managing the users of the directory. Is there any way to do this via an API?

Comment: Connect to it like a normal Active Directory server (rather than using an AWS API call).

Answer (score 0):

The Directory Service documentation suggests that the supported method of management is not via AWS APIs but rather via Active Directory management tools, simply connecting to the domain controllers. There is one user management endpoint in the DS API, namely ResetPassword. The WorkSpaces console (but not the API) allows user creation, and while the WorkDocs API appears to allow user creation, deletion, etc. it seems that those operations are only possible when the directory is enabled for WorkDocs, which [may not be desirable](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/12021/39089) if you're not actually using the service.

Answer (score -2):

There is no API for that.

You must use Microsoft's tool for managing Active Directory users / groups.